# Организация ssh тоннеля средствами python

Tags: python, ssh

Обычными средствами linux делаю туннель так:

```
ssh -R 22:localhost:5551 login@IP
```

Всё работает на ура. Теперь хочу сделать тоже самое, но из под питона.

Можете объяснить пример:

```
import paramiko
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder

with SSHTunnelForwarder(
    (REMOTE_SERVER_IP, 443),
    ssh_username="",
    ssh_pkey="/var/ssh/rsa_key",
    ssh_private_key_password="secret",
    remote_bind_address=(PRIVATE_SERVER_IP, 22),
    local_bind_address=('0.0.0.0', 10022)
) as tunnel:
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.load_system_host_keys()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect('127.0.0.1', 10022)
    # do some operations with client session
    client.close()

print('FINISH!')
```

и скопируется ли таким образом публичный ключ(как например это могло быть средствами ssh-copy-id)

Comment: Примеры друг другу не соответствуют.  Ни один из примеров не копирует сам по себе публичные ключи. Есть ли какая мотивация, чтобы с помощью paramiko тунель строить вместо запуска внешней команды: `ssh -R`, которая работает для вас?

Comment: согласен с @jfs - не заморачивайтесь, сделайте Popen("ssh -R 22:localhost:5551 login@IP") и будем вам счастье